# Integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} e^{-\frac{\| x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx$ using Spherical coordiantes

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I know that, the inetegral 
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{\frac{n}{2}}} e^{-\frac{\| x-\mu\|^2}{2}} dx
\end{align}
integrates to $1$.

This can be shown as follows
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{( x_i- \mu_i)^2}{2}} dx
\end{align}
and see that every inetegral is equal to $1$.

My question is how to do this by using spherical coordinates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously $\mu$ is completely irrelevant: it can be removed by a suitable translation.
By Fubini's theorem
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left(-\|x\|^2\right)\,dx = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)^n = \pi^{n/2} $$
and the claim readily follows. Have a look at the first pages of [*Keith Ball, An Elementary Introduction to Modern Convex Geometry*](http://library.msri.org/books/Book31/files/ball.pdf). If you want to use spherical coordinates, well, just use them by computing the determinant of the involved jacobian matrix.

Comment: I know $\mu$ can be dropped. The reason I kept it to to see, how to works with spherical coordinates when the function is shifted. Thank you for the reference. I am reading it right now. It is very good.

Comment: The reason, I was interested in this question. Is the question I posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240910/set-of-on-which-a-certain-function-is-negative

Answer (score 1):

We can write the integral of interest as

$$\begin{align}
I&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-\frac12||\vec x-\vec \mu||^2}\,d^n\vec x\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{S_{n-1}} \color{blue}{\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac12r ^2}\,r^{n-1}\,dr}\,dS_{n-1}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\int_{S_{n-1}} \color{blue}{\left(\frac12 2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)\right)}\,dS_{n-1}\\\\
&\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\color{blue}{\left(\frac12 2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)\right)}\color{red}{\int_{S_{n-1}}(1)\,dS_{n-1}}\\\\
&\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\color{blue}{\left(\frac12 2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)\right)}\color{red}{\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}}\\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

> A good summary for analysis of the $n$-Sphere in spherical coordinates can be found [HERE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The motivation for this question what something that I asked here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2240910/set-of-on-which-a-certain-function-is-negative